# For every ID in the table, count how many times that ID appears in another Column. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Table: MyTable

[[image: My Table1]

Here is the result I desire:

For every ID in the table, count how many times that ID appears in the column Parent_ID.
Create a custom column AS `Instances` to place the result.

My desired Result

[image: My Result]

I imagine to get the above result with something not more complicated than a working version of the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Parent_ID, COUNT( Parent_ID = ID ) AS Instances FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *scalar subquery* to compute the extra column. For example:

```
select
  id,
  parent_id,
  (
    select count(*) from my_table b where b.parent_id = a.id
  ) as instances
from my_table a
```

Comment: sorry I am new to SQL. I wonder why a.id can be recognized within the subquery? My understanding is the sub query doesn't have table a.

Comment: @sweetlemon That's right, the subquery does not have a table `a`. However, this is a "scalar subquery"; these are queries that take the place of one expression in the select list; they return one column and one row only (degree = 1 and cardinality = 1). Now, scalar subqueries can access tables or views present in the outer query(ies), and that's why `a` is recognized and makes the subquery highly dependent on each row of the main query.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is the simplest solution:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.parent_id = t.id) as instances
from mytable t;
```